# BLOB or XML for saving XSD in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, entity-framework, xsd, blob

I have an application where I'm about to save an XSD- or XML-file to DB. I use a SQL Server 2008 R2 (or later) with Entity Framework. I have a form where the user will upload a XSD or XML file. The contents of this file should be stored in DB.

I will never have to look at the specific contents of the XML/XSD once it's stored in the DB, but it will be downloaded later on.

As I see it, I have two approaches:

**Approach A.**

1. Upload file.
2. Read contents of file.
3. Save contents of file as XML.

**Approach B.**

1. Upload file.
2. Save file as BLOB.

What's the better option here, or is there a (better) third option as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach C.**

1. Save XSD file to shared access storage
2. Store the path in SQL server

> I will never have to look at the specific contents of the XML/XSD

So why put it in the DB at all?

> it will be downloaded later on

Much easier to retrieve it from a file share than a DB.

Comment: You're absolutely right. The thing is that my architect wanted it to be stored in DB, and together with other info regarding the same model.

Comment: @smoksnes - sounds exactly like the kind of thing an architect would ask for ;p IMO it's six-of-one, half a dozen of the other. Just go with the option which requires you to write the least code then...